# Azure app is asking for authentication all the time

Tags: development, azure, microsoft-graph

I have created azure app with by taking reference from [MS Samples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample). When i run this sample it is working fine. I have created new solution with by refering some of the points in this solution. When I run the application, it is asking me for authentication which is good. But unfortunately even I login it is asking for password again and again. But when I click on "Back" button in the screen it is taking me to the actual application (in my case it is https://localhost:23432). 
What could be reason for asking signin for multiple times? It is coming to below url after signin as well.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=a0c2773f-4756-4d9b-b197-c4ca6cb531c1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44329%2F&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20offline_access%20User.Read&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3Dsl11mPQXOr4xZU7CJl0HcOGUYz2VXCemvABnmbPmbJiEOJDqc4lTdHb0qk-VhPsMdvO5dO53zYnvJRYHXCTy5hjgIHkDh3tsgJf2gJn6xxgZArF1mDV_gyUEFVChrUMO7MA3gNYgsXFvohe071vYeh7eFfOXn76eX3XnqGecG6uE3YYQpYPzHIt5QC5BpqyaVLogHk3QhFlfCtsXR97eBQ&nonce=636590515214236239.ODg4NzY5YzMtZDc1Yi00MmIxLWFiNDQtMTA1MmJiOTQ4NDk3MTE0NmI2YWQtMDcyYS00NGNhLWI2ZjUtYWJjZjdmMzZiZWI5&x-client-SKU=ID_NET451&x-client-ver=5.2.1.0
```

If I try to sign in again then it is loading below url for authentication

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/reprocess?ctx=rQIIAXWSu2_TUBTG47pJH0hQIYZKLBmYQHHu9StxpA5t3KRuHDt17CTOQOQ4N7FT2ze13bw2JFZEJwaQkGCqOjIhZlg6VRn5E5gQYkBCSISnxMDyDUff7-jofN_mGkfRFKTAXZKmQOGOBWw6l2P6GTYHYIbtCd1MFwq5jM3aFm93OQbaMLy5uaW9e_to_Pyr-DC87zxoFJ9dENtOHI-iQjbrYdvyHBzFBZZlaCH7miCuCOJiJeIZnhMAR0PI87zACjBPtX2DMZuaW20asTJ0huYMgKp4xMnNQ7fqHy1nDV_VpVm1eQRNvzpVyxJj6rugWl76yyZs1wEw5waU9QFQ5lKsiM6xOTTny31A1UvH71duqLunsUP_EBy6c_RpZaOPQ78zWh74lPxGqCMUSL0iDgJkx9QPGwpi17ZiFwe1EI9QGLso2ul4zLwNhp0D1Gq641NuWqlwGRWWeTqv5hSMai1pdsLpjXzLqckRmtCOcRqHdL8qzLWS0dIlNHTkMa9qLj0xKkXWr5l1H2uDpmd2bb1YnNV8iE-mDZkPG_V-2NtTgpJ6auQ7unQA9gNpIs28YokV7bEp68qkCwSYsQz5cNLSjVJb5vYrDQkKQ9pxc8ZEquNBTgR1XTtRgqmeUeoaGu22gkCcjGdTo2jEXr2N6_7ggrz9J7VBaI0cynftEEe4H1M29l-RqaX6OLgkM8tHBG4vjXzL9dKjEPddD6Vxv--5AepYto2iKG1EKKQ0ZPUWZOqXf0EmfxILcu03syCv_0styI2_3NUq8WH11npya2WbSCcAWVhf39xKbCfSiS-rxMvksnbnn8tPFpXHu-cvstpZ5VriPElcJrN5-eSA6e6J3VakWsVZjp8htcyIXRn2mj25ciRV7mkjVjd9JdqBBXiWIs5SqcvUhiR2lH2d5eDHVOLNxn8L_B01&sessionid=406cc0e0-8985-42c1-93f0-498b96326e10

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to Allow Implicit Flow? Its in step 8 of your above in link: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample

Make sure the Allow Implicit Flow check box is selected, and enter http://localhost:55065/ as the Redirect URI.

The Allow Implicit Flow option enables the hybrid flow. During authentication, this enables the app to receive both sign-in info (the id_token) and artifacts (in this case, an authorization code) that the app can use to obtain an access token.

Comment: Yes I did. But if I create a new solution and use the same id then it started working. Something was messed up with my solution

Comment: Ok great, glad it worked.